# How to binding data of sql server 2012 to datagrid in Silverlight APP

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, data-binding

I am trying to biding data for a database in SQL server 2012 on SilverLight application.
But, when i was following this tutorial for beginner at 16th step, i could not find out my
"context" ( "OrganizationContext" in the tutorial) to get data from my database.

This is that tutorial:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2

I don't know where the code, is generated from my database, is in my project. I tried to find "context" in the sample of this tutorial, it's difinited in HRapp.Web.g.cs file of sample, which i can't find out where it's in project folder in window explorer.

Please someone show me how to get my "context" to get data from database or give me a hint/guide to binding data from SQL2012 database to datagrid in SilverLight.

P/s: my English is bad. Please forgive me. And i tried many tutorial but non of them guide me how to binding with SQL2012 in SilverLight App.

Comment: That "context" thing should be your DatabaseContext that is autogenerated by the EntityFramework (supposed you've done the mapping correctly). You can find it if you expand your .edmx file that EF created for you when you specified which DB to use.

Comment: i really don't understand. Normally, a project of SilverLight have 2 project: ABC(project contains  MainPage.xaml/cs)  and  ABC.web ( contains file aspx/html). How could  we add database on  ABC.web  and make  the ABC.cs see that database. Because they are 2 different project.

Comment: I tried to add WebService,which supports my database.Because  this Tutorial  created service bas on ADO.net,is created from database. But i don't know how to add method into my service so that on ABC project i can use those method to get data as SOAP.( p/s: i used a SOAP before but  i don't know how to edit it).PLease help me.

Comment: To use your Context from the .edmx file just add a reference to the respective project where your DB mapping is created.

Answer (score 0):

So here's an example with pictures:

In order to find use your data context class you have to, as people said above, add a reference to the project that contains your edmx file. In the picture below, my edmx file is in the BOS.Model project under the EF folder.

On my web service I would then add a reference to that project and folder as pictured below on the left side of the picture.

[image: edmx file location]

With that reference in place, I can create a data context like this:

```
var context = new BOSEntities()
```

The class `BosEntities` is automatically created by Entity Framework when I mapped my database.

If you want to know what this class would be for your project, simply click on your edmx file to open it, right click in any open space in the diagram, and click properties.

The name of your class will be shown in the Entity Container Name property as shown here:

[image]